# jquery auto complete not working for dynamically generated id's

Tags: jquery

my code looks like

```
<div class="my-form">
  <p class="text-box">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="boxes[]" id="Name" value=""  placeholder="Name" onchange="javascript:callid(this.id);" />
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="boxes[]" value="" id="box1" placeholder="Stripes" />
  <a class="add-box" href="#">Add More</a>
  </p>
 </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function callid(id)
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                $("#"+id+"").autocomplete(
                {
                    source:'autocomplete.php',
                    minLength:1
                });
            });

    </script>
```

Comment: why are you altering my answer,alter your question

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  <div class="my-form">
      <p class="text-box">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="boxes[]" id="Name" value=""  placeholder="Name" />
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="boxes[]" value="" id="box1" placeholder="Stripes" />
      <a class="add-box" href="#">Add More</a>
      </p>
     </div>
      <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function()
                {
                    $('input[name="boxes[]"]').autocomplete(
                    {
                        source:'autocomplete.php',
                        minLength:1
                    });
                });
        </script>
```

Note: if you have dynamically added input boxes then you need to call autcomplete for each newly added item